# Is model/view programming good start point for an Qt beginner?

Tags: c++, qt

As a beginner of Qt and C++, I am interested to know, is [Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) good start point? Does that kind of thinking about Qt programming helps beginners to understand Qt app development?

Comment: Model/View programming isn’t about the rather general MVC design pattern, but about a somewhat more specific subset of Qt meant for providing data for list, tree and table views. (with QtQuick it’s slightly more generic, but still not a general pattern). So no, that’s not where I would start with Qt.

Comment: So @FrankOsterfeld, at first it is recommended to finish C++ Primer by Lippman and then to go to Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helps to learn a new programming language and/or library is to have a real problem you can solve using it.  Even if the problem is simple, or for a game or a contest, or already solved by others.  You should look for something to do using Qt, then do it.  If you can't find anything to do using Qt, you shouldn't bother learning it!

Answer (score 0):

No, the Model View stuff is quite difficult to understand.  Start with a simple app using some simple widgets directly.  Also, work on your C++ before you get carried away with Qt.  C++ is hard enough on its own.

Comment: I am learning C++ next to that from C++ Primer 5th edition by Lippman, is it good reference for C++?

Comment: Don't know about that book in particular.  Do some command line projects of your own with no tricky user interface first though,  Or do some exercises from the web: I've heard [these](http://www.spoj.com/problems/classical/) are good (not tried them myself).